# Adding a table in a word footer using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a table in a footer of .docx using excel vba.

At the end the macro will change some markers in my .docx, and the footer can be different. thats why i want to use excel.

Here is my code but i have a 91 error, idk why. any advice is welcome :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()

    
'Déclaration des variables
    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Dim word_app As Word.Application
    Dim word_fichier As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim fichier As String

    
'On récupère le fichier test
    
    fichier = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.docx"

'Ouverture de word
        Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        With word_app
            .Visible = True
            .WindowState = 1
        End With
        
'Test tableau bas de page
    With word_fichier
            Set tbl = .Tables.Add(word_fichier.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, 2, 2)
    End With
    
    With tbl
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "test"
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You have declared Word_fischer but you don't assign anything to it. Hence its value will be nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to open the word document, here it is the new code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()

    
'Déclaration des variables
    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Dim word_app As Word.Application
    Dim word_fichier As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim fichier As String
    Dim ListeBordures As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    
    
'On récupère le fichier test
    
    fichier = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.docx"

'Ouverture de word
        Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        With word_app
            .Visible = True
            .WindowState = 1
            Set word_fichier = .Documents.Open(fichier)
        End With
        
'Test tableau bas de page
   With word_fichier
        Set tbl = .Tables.Add(.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, 1, 1)
        With tbl
             .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "test"
        End With
   End With
End Sub
```

It's "working" but i want the "test" in a table like this : [image]

Instead of this (that i want, i used paint to do that) : [image]

Answer (score 1):

`wdHeaderFooterPrimary` is a Word constant (see [WdHeaderFooterIndex enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdheaderfooterindex)) and does not exist in Excel. So you need to use its value instead.

```
Set tbl = .Tables.Add(word_fichier.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range, 2, 2)
```

Alternatively you need to define it before using it:

```
Const wdHeaderFooterPrimary As Long = 1
Set tbl = .Tables.Add(word_fichier.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, 2, 2)
```

Comment: @PeH Even if i added "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" i cant use wdHeaderFooterPrimary ? I tried your way but i still have the same error :(

Comment: @julien1h Ah sorry well I didn't expect that you added the library because you used late binding `CreateObject("Word.Application")` and the library is only needed for early binding.

Comment: @PeH, i found my error, i forgot to open my .docx. I added the line ```Set word_fichier = .Documents.Open(fichier)``` and it's "working", ill post an answer to my question